# Unable to load class oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle Driver after making connection to DB2 first in robot frameowrk

Tags: robotframework

I was trying to connect to Oracle Database after validating one SQL query in IBM DB2 but getting an error RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable:java.lang.RuntimeException Class oracle.jdbc.driver.Oracle Driver not found.

However same script is running if I am commenting out the DB2 SQL connection and validation part but not working when both the steps are included and throwing class not found exception. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

jdbc driver is present in lib folder of my project and same I have mentioned in CLASSPATH as well
I am running above script in robotframework and connection is done through jaydebeapi

Answer (score 0):

Run the test with `jybot` (RobotFramework using Jython).